# How to normalize mfcc or melspectogram as input to cnn?

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, normalization, image-classification

For Binary Audio Classification I wanted to input mfcc or melspectogram into a CNN.

If I compute the mfcc or melspectogram over audio data, then a huge value range might be the output.

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
audio, sample_rate = librosa.load("example.wav", res_type='kaiser_fast')
padded_audio, sr = pad_trunc((audio, sample_rate), 4000) # add padding or trunk to exaclty have 4 sec duration
melspec = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=padded_audio, sr=sr, n_mels=64, n_fft=1024)
spec_melscale = librosa.power_to_db(melspec)
spec = np.expand_dims(spec_melscale, axis=-1) # expand dims to have shape (64, 172, 1) for cnn input
print(spec)
```

A possible output could be the following, resulting in min value of -61.5986 and max value of 20.580242 (after applying np.min and np.max function one times to the array):

```
array([[[-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        ...,
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385]],

       [[-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        ...,
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385]],

       [[-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        ...,
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385]],

       ...,

       [[-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        ...,
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385]],

       [[-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        ...,
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385]],

       [[-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        ...,
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385],
        [-59.5385]]], dtype=float32)
```

With mfccs instead of melspectogram the value range is bigger up to minimum value of even -625.0.

But as input for neuronal networks input range between 0 and 1 or -1 and 1 is recommended.

I thought about putting this librosa normalize method before np.expand_dims(...):

```
melnormalized = librosa.util.normalize(spec_melscale) # normalizes between -1 and 1
```

Is this normalization possible or does it change the features itself to something wrong?
If not how do I normalize melspectogram or mfcc correctly for input into CNN model? I am thinking about a per sample normalization not the std deviation and mean normalization of a whole dataset, because I need it to use the same preprocessing for production usage of that cnn model as well and there I would not have a complete dataset to normalize live input of a stream. Or does this work for production usage as well even if I use std deviation and mean normalization?

My last question is: I am trying to detecting Dog barks and this should be used for production at home. Typical the training files of a dataset are very long (varying from 4 sec up to 10 sec duration). What is the most ideal duration for audio classification? I thought about 1 sec duration as input instead of 4 sec. But this seems to be a lot of effort to shorten the audio files of the datasets and relabeling them (at least for the dog bark positive ones). The relabelling is needed because if I shorten a 4sec dog barking audio file into 1 sec clips as input for cnn then there can be one of those 1 sec clips where the dog is not barking. So, I need to relabel. Does the shortening of the files have any advantages? Or is the feature set about the 4 sec containing just more than one bark also fine.